# fread storing value incorrectly?

Tags: c

I have a binary file, that when I fread I store the value, I then fwrite the same value to a new binary file, but the value that is stored is different to the one I read.

When I print the value its correct? So im unsure as to why the written value is different.

I've written up a basic view of the relavent code I have.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Data
{
  char phone;
  long long int cheese;
  double chicken;
}

int main(){

FILE *data_input;
FILE *output_file;
int array_size=10;

data_input=fopen("input.bin","rb");
output_file=fopen("output.bin","wb");

struct Data *input_array;
input_array=malloc(sizeof(struct Data)*array_size);

fread(&input_array->phone, sizeof(input_array->phone), 1, data_input);
fread(&input_array->cheese, sizeof(input_array->cheese), 1, data_input);
fread(&input_array->chicken, sizeof(input_array->chicken, 1, data_input);

printf("%i, %llx, %f \n", input_array->phone, input_array->cheese, input_array->chicken);

flcose(data_input);
free(input_array);

fwrite(&intput_array->phone, sizeof(input_array->phone), 1, output_file);
fwrite(&intput_array->cheese, sizeof(input_array->cheese), 1, output_file);
fwrite(&intput_array->chicken, sizeof(input_array->chicken), 1, output_file);

fclose(output_file);
return 0;
}
```

The printf results are:

```
0, bd6130, -6.351429
```

when I use od -t x1 input.bin the bytes are:

```
00 30 61 bd 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 dd 67 19 c0
```

when I use od -t x1 output.bin the bytes are:

```
00 10 a0 72 fb 3b 56 00 00 00 00 00 00 dd 67 19 c0
```

I don't understand why the byte values are different, for the value of cheese.

Comment: because of `free(input_array)`

Comment: `"fb"` -> `"rb"`. And you definitely need to check check if `fopen` succeeds. There mey be more problems though.

Comment: The code you posted seems to not be the code you are using ... because there are just too many 'typo' errors in it. But is the mode of the input file really `"fb"`? If so, what does the `f` mean?

Comment: Sorry that was typo, its actually "rb" in my code

Comment: Do not retype code to post in Stack Overflow. Prepare a [mre] and then copy and paste the **exact text** of the code into the question.

Comment: Maybe also address the other typos: missing semicolon after the structure, a missing `)` in one of your `fread` calls ... and what is `intput_array`?

Comment: You free `input_array` and then you continue using it! Are you doing this on purpose???

Comment: Re "*its actually "rb" in my code*" Do no post code you didn't actually run. Such lies can hurt you.

Comment: In fairness, not everyone is doing their coding on a machine with Internet access, so sometimes, sadly, retyping (with its terrible inherent risk of inaccuracy) is unavoidable.

Comment: You presumably mean `fclose()` rather than `flcose()`.  Please read [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

Do not free `input_array` until you make sure it is no longer used.

BTW, there are some typos.

```c
struct Data
{
  char phone;
  long long int cheese;
  double chicken;
};

int main(){

FILE *data_input;
FILE *output_file;
int array_size=10;

data_input=fopen("input.bin","rb");
output_file=fopen("output.bin","wb");

struct Data *input_array;
input_array=malloc(sizeof(struct Data)*array_size);

fread(&input_array->phone, sizeof(input_array->phone), 1, data_input);
fread(&input_array->cheese, sizeof(input_array->cheese), 1, data_input);
fread(&input_array->chicken, sizeof(input_array->chicken), 1, data_input);

printf("%i, %llx, %f \n", input_array->phone, input_array->cheese, input_array->chicken);

fclose(data_input);

fwrite(&input_array->phone, sizeof(input_array->phone), 1, output_file);
fwrite(&input_array->cheese, sizeof(input_array->cheese), 1, output_file);
fwrite(&input_array->chicken, sizeof(input_array->chicken), 1, output_file);

fclose(output_file);
free(input_array); // never used again
return 0;
}
```